# Editing screen shots for 5.5 screens, 4.0 screens, 3.5 screens and iPad screens after the app is ready for sales

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I've recently uploaded an update for one of my iPhone apps and now the app is just turned to be ready for sale , but I only update iPhone 6 screenshots but not the others. It has now dawned on me that they are old screens for the new game, which might be confusing for users.

Is there anyway to upload the new screenshots without submitting a new binary?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the iTunes Connect and how to update images shown in the app store.

Comment: @Raju there is now way to update screenshots without submitting a new binary

Comment: That mean I have to reject the binary first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to submit a new binary since iTunesConnect only allows updates whenever a new version is up.